# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

**Please skip and jump directly to my update 4 below. I have summarised the problem in a better way.**

I'm using mysql (not sure if I'm using mariadb)

When I do a rails db:migrate, I got this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of
'./my_database_name/#sql-228c_e' to './my_database_name/apples' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE
`apples` CHANGE `gardener_id` `farmer_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
```

I think I got this error because of this file:

```
# db/migrate/20171017044807_rename_gardeners_to_farmers.rb
class RenamegardenersToFarmers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_table :gardeners, :farmers
  end
end
```

My app works fine and `rails db:migrate` work fine after I removed the `rename_table` line above and go through all my migration files and change all `gardeners` word to `farmers` word. So I think the problem is indeed about renaming.

My question is why is it a problem and how do I fix it?

**Update 1**

Sorry, I just rerun the migration files until # db/migrate/20171017044807_rename_gardeners_to_farmers.rb (inclusive) and actually this file does not cause problem. It's the next migration file that cause problem.

The schema just after running migration file `db/migrate/20171017044807_rename_gardeners_to_farmers.rb`:

```
  create_table "apples", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.bigint "gardener_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["gardener_id"], name: "index_apples_on_gardener_id"
  end
  add_foreign_key "apples", "farmers", column: "gardener_id"
```

The next migration file that cause the above error:

```
# 20171017051611_rename_gardener_id_column_for_apples.rb
class RenameGardenerIdColumnForApples < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_column :apples, :gardener_id, :farmer_id
  end
end
```

**Update 2**
Trying to solve the problem after hearing Ngoral's answer, I tried to add a migration just before the failed one with the content: `change_column :apples, :gardener_id, :references, null: false` but it doesn't work.

By 'does not work', I mean I see migration failing error when I try to run `rails db:migrate` after adding the new migration file that contains the line I show on the first comment to your answer.

The error is this:

```
rails db:migrate
== 20171017044808 PreventGardenerIdNull: migrating ==============================
-- change_column(:apples, :gardener_id, :references, {:null=>false})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'references NOT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `apples` CHANGE `gardener_id` `gardener_id` references NOT NULL
```

**Update 3**

I think the error in update 2 shows me that there is somehting wrong with the code I wrote, so I change it from
`change_column :apples, :gardener_id, :references, null: false`
to
`change_column_null :replies, :author_id, false`
The reason I did this is because I saw it in Ngoral's comment below (to her won answer) and this Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20255645/6359753

Now after I re-run `rails db:migrate`, I got this:

```
rails db:migrate
== 20171017044808 PreventGardenerIdNull: migrating <--------this is the migration file I added in Update 2==============================
-- change_column_null(:apples, :gardener_id, false)
   -> 0.0068s
== 20171017044808 PreventGardenerIdNull: migrated (0.0069s) =====================

== 20171017051611 RenameGardenerIdColumnForApples: migrating ===================
-- rename_column(:apples, :gardener_id, :farmer_id)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of './my_database_name/#sql-71a_3' to './my_database_name/apples' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE `apples` CHANGE `gardener_id` `farmer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
```

From what I can see, it seems like the problem is not to do with gardener_id can be null because the migration file `PreventGardenerIdNull` succeed and `RenameGardenerIdColumnForApples` failed.

Note: I think I somehow violate my foreign key constraint, according to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4061333/6359753, but I'm still figuring out what exactly went wrong.
Note: `mysql -u root` shows that my mariaDB server version is: `Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server`

**Update 4:**
I think after all the investigations and the answer here, I can summarise the question a bit better now:

1) Ignore everything in this question post above

2) `mysql -u root` shows that my mariaDB server version is: `Server version: 5.5.56-MariaDB MariaDB Server`

3) Below are displayed in the order of time:

[Time = 1] Schema 1:

```
  create_table "gardeners", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "apples", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.bigint "gardener_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["gardener_id"], name: "index_apples_on_gardener_id"
  end
  add_foreign_key "apples", "gardeners"
```

[Time = 2] Run migration with code:

```
rename_table :gardeners, :farmers
```

[Time = 3] Schema 2:

```
  create_table "farmers", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "apples", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.bigint "gardener_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["gardener_id"], name: "index_apples_on_gardener_id"
  end
  add_foreign_key "apples", "farmers", column: "gardener_id"
```

[Time = 4] Run migration with code:

```
rename_column :apples, :gardener_id, :farmer_id
```

Got error:

```
== 20171017051611 RenameGardenerIdColumnForApples: migrating ===================
-- rename_column(:apples, :gardener_id, :farmer_id)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of './my_database_name/#sql-71a_3' to './my_database_name/apples' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE `apples` CHANGE `gardener_id` `farmer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
```

[Time = 5] (never happen) the schema I want to change to:

```
  create_table "farmers", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "apples", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.bigint "gardener_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["gardener_id"], name: "index_apples_on_gardener_id"
  end
  add_foreign_key "apples", "gardeners"
```

I have 2 questions:

1) Why do I fail at [time = 4]

2) What migration code should I have used at [time = 4], or, what migration code should I have used at [time = 2] to prevent all these problems?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, provide a schema for `apples` tables. The problem is there, in `gardeners_id`.

Comment: Sorry, I rerun the migration files until `# db/migrate/20171017044807_rename_gardeners_to_farmers.rb
` (inclusive) and actually this file does not cause problem. It's the next migration file that cause problem

Comment: Sorry, I just rerun the migration files until # db/migrate/20171017044807_rename_gardeners_to_farmers.rb (inclusive) and actually this file does not cause problem. It's the next migration file that cause the above error I mentioned

Comment: Could `gardener_id` be `nil`? Not by your schema (I see it), but by logic and reality

Comment: I don't think gardener_id can be nil

Comment: So, the answer is below =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using MariaDB version 5.5.64. I changed to using MariaDB version 10.4 and this issue for migration goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227199/mysql-errno-150) question.

The problem is caused by `DEFAULT NULL` statement which is called by migration and can clearly be seen in your SQL dump. Such statement is incorrect for `InnoDB` which you using (it is seen from the schema).

So, I would guess you do not want `gardener_id` to be nil. In this case, creating a migration that sets `null: false` for `gardener_id` should help.

So, you first create a migration not to allow `gardener_id` to be nil and then put your migration that fails now.

============
Answering your questions after update:
Your migration fails at step 4 with the reason I stated above: you have a null default value for `gardener_id` and this is not allowed by your DB.

You should run a migration with a command `change_column_null :apples, :gardener_id, false` before renaming. And after changing the default null, run your renaming migration.
The command you run has invalid syntax and it clearly tells you so.

Comment: Do you know how do I set it to not null in a migration?     I try to add a migration just before the failed one with the content: `change_column :apples, :gardener_id, :references, null: false` but it doesn't work. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean saying 'does not work'? It does not changes null to false or does not help to solve your problem? If first, try a `change_column_null :apples, :gardener_id, false`

Comment: Try the command I gave: `change_column_null`, the syntax you use in your command is incorrect. `:references` is not needed there.

Comment: I think that's what I did in update 3, can you please have a look again? If  I made some mistake in my code, please tell me